# How to get an object of my model (POJO) class from Firestore?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am testing Firestore to be more familiar and to implement in my project but for some reason I cannot get an object of POJO class back from the database. I know I can get the data as a Map but I want my POJO class. I have followed many answers to help get me started but I cannot solve this. This my code:

```
mDocumentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            UserPOJO pojo = (UserPOJO) task.getResult(); //Error
        }
    }
});
```

getResult() is not helping me. So I have added my data with POJO and my question is, how to get it back as a POJO?

**My POJO:**

```
public class UserPOJO {
    private String name, email, id, college, state;
    private int age, number;

    public UserPOJO() {
    }

    public UserPOJO(String name, String email, String id, String college, String state, int age, int number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.id = id;
        this.college = college;
        this.state = state;
        this.age = age;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCollege() {
        return college;
    }

    public void setCollege(String college) {
        this.college = college;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

My error:

**error: incompatible types: DocumentSnapshot cannot be converted to UserPOJO**

Comment: When posting on stack overflow, please post all relevant code (including your POJO), the error message you received (typically the entire exception stack trace), and the contents of the database that you expect to read.  Without all this information, there's no way we tell what's going wrong for you.

Comment: @DougStevenson Added POJO and error. Thanks!

Comment: @ErolEngineer I was expecting an error like that. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get a `UserPOJO` object when calling `getResult()` method on the `task` object because it will never return such an object, it will return a `DocumentSnapshot` object. Even if you cast it to a `UserPOJO` object, it will not help you at all. There is no way in Java to cast a `DocumentSnapshot` object to a `UserPOJO` because there is no relationship between them.

From the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), this is how you can get an object of `UserPOJO` class back from the database:

```
mDocumentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                //Get an object of type UserPOJO
                UserPOJO pojo = document.toObject(UserPOJO.class);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See, the key for solving this problem is to use [DocumentSnapshot.toObject()'s](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#toObject(java.lang.Class<T>)) method.

Comment: Yes, it's working. I will use toObject function. Thanks!

Comment: Helpful. Thanks!